# A problem on recursive functions

Tags: functions

Given the function,

$$f(n)= 
\begin{cases}
\ n-3 \quad  \text{ if }\quad n\ge1000\\
 \\
f (f (n+5)) \quad\text{ if } \quad n<1000
\end{cases}
$$

What is the value of $f (83)-f (84) $?

---

One of my friends gave me this problem.
I tried to find a pattern for the numbers but couldn't. I programmed the recursive function on C++ and got $1$ as the answer.

Comment: Your program constitutes a mathematical proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that $f(n)=997+(n \bmod 2)$ for $n<1000$. (Actually, for $n\le 1001$.)